# Doesn't close() flush the buffers?

Tags: python

```
# cat write_file.py
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

f=open("/tmp/write_test", "w")
f.write("test string\n")
f.close

#f=open("/tmp/write_test", "r")
#f.close


os.system("ls -l /tmp/write_test")
os.system("cat /tmp/write_test")
```

Calling produces no output (`write_test` is empty), but after the python script finishes executing, the string is there.

```
# ./write_file.py 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 25 18:29 /tmp/write_test
# ls -la /tmp/write_test 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12 Apr 25 18:29 /tmp/write_test
# cat /tmp/write_test 
test string
```

Opening the file for reading and closing it immediately before `os.system()` works.
My understanding was that `close()` calls `flush()` and that all the data should land in the file. What do I miss?

Python version is 3.9.3

Comment: You're calling `f.close` instead of `f.close()`

Comment: Notice how your question title says `close()` in it, but your *code* does *not*?

Comment: Ah, great. Thanks, it works now. UPD: I was hoping that such typos would be caught by some built-in validator =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as @chemicalwill pointed out you are not actually calling the close function, you are calling it as a variable. To "run" a function you must call it with the parens i.e.

```
f = open("/tmp/write_test", "w")
f.write("test string\n")
f.close()
```

As a final thought. It is worth exploring the `with` statement in python. It is considered standard to use this for file IO. It will automatically close out your file when it goes out of scope.

```
with open("/tmp/write_test", "w") as f:
    f.write("test string\n")

# f is now closed by python itself, as it is out of scope
```

[docs for more](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)